# Try to get data in "loginUserReducer" of redux but not successfull

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern

I get data in localstorage  but I didn't get the data in "loginUserReducer". Which is a reducer for login for the [Image of loginUserReducer from reudx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXkjX.png) 
[Image of loaclstorage where I get the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F2YS.png)

//userReducer.js:

```
//Register Reducer
export const registerUserReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "USER_REGISTER_REQUEST":
      return {
        loading: true,
      };
    case "USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS":
      return {
        loading: false,
        success: true,
      };
    case "USER_REGISTER_FAIL":
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return { state };
  }
};

//Login Reducer
export const loginUserReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST":
      return {
        loading: true,
      };
    case "USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        loading: false,
        success: true,
        currentUser: action.payload,
      };
    case "USER_LOGIN_FAIL":
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

//store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { getAllPizzaReducer } from "./reducers/pizzaReducer";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/cartReducer";
import { registerUserReducer, loginUserReducer } from "./reducers/userReducer";

//Getting cartItems from local storage
const cartItems = localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
  : [];

//Getting current user from local storage
const currentUser = localStorage.getItem("currentUser")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"))
  : null;

const reducers = combineReducers({
  getAllPizzaReducer: getAllPizzaReducer,
  cartReducer: cartReducer,
  registerUserReducer: registerUserReducer,
  loginUserReducer: loginUserReducer,
});

const initialState = {
  cartReducer: {
    cartItems: cartItems,
  },
  loginUserReducer: {
    currentUser: currentUser,
  },
};
const middleware = [thunk];

const strore = configureStore(
  { reducer: reducers },
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default strore;
```

//Login.jsx:

```
const Login = () => {
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const dispatch = useDispatch()

const loginState = useSelector((state) => state.loginUserReducer);
  const { error, success, loading } = loginState;


useEffect(() =>{
  if(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")){
    window.location.href = "/"
  }
},[])

const loginHandler = () => {
  const user ={email,password}
  dispatch(loginUser(user))
}

  return (
    <>
    <Container>
    {loading && <Loader />}
        {success && <Success success="User Logged In Successfully" />}
        {error && <Error error="somthing went wrong" />}

    <Form>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter email" />
        <Form.Text className="text-muted">
          We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        </Form.Text>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}placeholder="Password" />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary"  onClick={loginHandler}>
        Login
      </Button>
    </Form>
    </Container>
    </>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

//NavBar.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, Image, DropdownButton,Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import { logoutUser } from "../actions/userAction";
const NavBar = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cartState = useSelector((state) => state.cartReducer);
  const userState = useSelector((state) => state.loginUserReducer);
  const { currentUser } = userState;
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="light" variant="light">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <Image
              src="images/logo.png"
              alt="logo"
              style={{ height: "50px" }}
            />
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ms-auto">
              {currentUser ? (
                <LinkContainer to="/">
                  <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title={currentUser.name}>
                      <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Orders</Dropdown.Item>
                      <Dropdown.Item onClick={()=>{dispatch(logoutUser())}}> Logout </Dropdown.Item>
                  </DropdownButton>
                </LinkContainer>
              ) : (
                <>
                  {" "}
                  <LinkContainer to="/login">
                    <Nav.Link>Login</Nav.Link>
                  </LinkContainer>
                  <LinkContainer to="/register">
                    <Nav.Link>Register</Nav.Link>
                  </LinkContainer>{" "}
                </>
              )}

              <LinkContainer to="/cart">
                <Nav.Link>Cart {cartState.cartItems.length}</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

I also add the codes for the understanding purpose. It will be very kind if anyone can help me with this issue

Comment: When is the `currentUser` value set in localStorage versus when it's read into, or dispatched, to the state?

Comment: Drew Reese when user logged in that time currentUser value will be set and using That  value I want to get the infromation of the user and also I want to use that currentUser value to logout

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. Please [edit] the post to clarify all the behaviors you are expecting the app to do, and note that this may require adding all the relevant code you are using to make for a more complete [mcve] so readers here can read all the code is doing and possibly see what the issue is.